# Using lodash to retrieve values from a complex array

Tags: lodash

I have the following complex array

```
[
   {
      label: "Country1",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 234184
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 145678
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      label: "Country2",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 123456
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 456789
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      label: "Country3",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 62389
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 4964738
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to convert it to the following simple array wherein from the metrics sub array the values for label and value becomes a key value pair.

```
[
    {label: “Country1”, xyz: 234184, abc: 145678},
    {label: “Country2”, xyz: 123456, abc: 456789},
    {label: “Country3”, xyz: 62389, abc: 4964738}
]
```

Can this conversion happen using lodash?

Comment: Your question has no code which makes it difficult for others to understand what you're doing and how you're going about it. Please update your post with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a **clear problem statement**.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better / cleaner way to do this, but this is what I could come up with in just a few minutes.

```js
const inputData = [
   {
      label: "Country1",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 234184
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 145678
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      label: "Country2",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 123456
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 456789
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      label: "Country3",
      metrics: [
         {
            label: "xyz",
            metric: "xyz",
            value: 62389
         },
         {
            label: "abc",
            metric: "abc",
            value: 4964738
         }
      ]
   }
];

const newData = _.map(inputData, first => {
  const additional = _.map(first.metrics, metric => [metric.label, metric.value]);
  return _.assign({}, _.fromPairs(additional), {
    label: first.label
  });
});
  
console.log(newData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that doesn't require lodash, you simply have to take advantage of using [**Array#map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each item in the top-level array, and then use [**Array#reduce**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform the object and get the rest of the properties you need. The methodology used below takes advantage of the following ES6 features:

1. [**Destructuring assignment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the properties from the `Array#map` and `Array#reduce` callbacks.
2. [**Spread Syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to combine properties of objects from different sources.
3. [**Computed property names**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931216/using-lodash-to-retrieve-values-from-a-complex-array/50958136#50958136) for a dynamic property name in an object.

---

```
var result = data.map(({ label, metrics }) =>
  metrics.reduce(
    (result, { metric, value }) => ({ ...result, [metric]: value }),
    { label }
  )
);
```

```js
var data = [{label:"Country1",metrics:[{label:"xyz",metric:"xyz",value:234184},{label:"abc",metric:"abc",value:145678}]},{label:"Country2",metrics:[{label:"xyz",metric:"xyz",value:123456},{label:"abc",metric:"abc",value:456789}]},{label:"Country3",metrics:[{label:"xyz",metric:"xyz",value:62389},{label:"abc",metric:"abc",value:4964738}]}];

var result = data.map(({ label, metrics }) =>
  metrics.reduce(
    (result, { metric, value }) => ({ ...result, [metric]: value }),
    { label }
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```